# ejb-javaee6 with error when generated by eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

When I create an ejb project through ejb-javaee6 archetype in Eclipse I get the following errors:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Endorsed directory '/home/hfluz/workspace/maven-test/web2/target/endorsed' is missing. You may need to a perform a Maven command line build in order to create it.  pom.xml /web2   line 28 Maven Configuration Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:copy (execution: default, phase: validate)    pom.xml /web2   line 53 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

- There is already an /target/endorsed/javaee-endorsed-api-6.0.jar file.
- IDE: JBoss Developer Studio 7 Beta 1 (tried with embedded 3.0.4 maven version and also with 3.0.5).
- When I generate this same archetype through command line (maven 3.0.4) and import the project to eclipse, these errors are not displayed.
- I just tried and the same happens with webapp-javaee6 archetype (also from org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes).

Anyone have any idea about what is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try refreshing the target folder in eclipse (workspace seems out of sync).

Read http://docs.jboss.org/tools/whatsnew/maven/maven-news-3.3.0.CR1.html about endorsed library support in JBDS/JBT

Comment: Thanks. Quickfix really solved the first issue. But the second issue (Type Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration) couldn't be fixed by eclipse quickfix. It just tries to find new m2e connectors, but it says no marketplace items are applicable.

Comment: As explained in the JBT website : "Please note that the maven-dependency-plugin execution is still not covered by m2e (this goes beyond the scope of this JIRA), thus requires custom lifecycle mapping (see http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered)."